# na.omit function is not removing rows containing NA

Tags: r

Hi there I am looking on the internet what is wrong and the `na.omit()` function is not removing the rows with NA. Could you please help me?

```
library(TTR)
library(quantmod)
library(doParallel) #this library is for parallel core processing

StartDate = "2010-01-01"
EndDate = "2020-03-20"
myStock <- c("AMZN")
getSymbols(myStock, src="yahoo", from=StartDate, to=EndDate)

gdat <-coredata(AMZN$AMZN.Close) # Create a 2-d array of all the data. Or...
Data <- data.frame(date=index(AMZN), coredata(AMZN)) # Create a data frame with the data and (optionally) maintain the date as an index

Data$rsi22 <- data.frame(RSI(Cl(Data), n=22))
Data$rsi44 <- data.frame(RSI(Cl(Data), n=44))
colnames(Data)

DatanoNA <- na.omit(Data) #remove rows with NAs
```

Comment: Where you create `rsi22` and `rsi44`, remove `data.frame()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `complete.cases()` function. `na.omit()` is for removing `NA` values in a vector, not for removing rows containing `NA` values from a data frame.

Also, your data frame construction is a little wonky (see below for more explanation). Try this:

```
Data <- data.frame(date=index(AMZN), coredata(AMZN),
                  rsi22=RSI(Cl(Data), n=22),
                  rsi44=RSI(Cl(Data), n=44))
nrow(Data)
nrow(Data[complete.cases(Data),])
```

---

Normally every column of a data frame is a vector. The results of `RSI()` are stored as a vector. When you say

```
Data$rsi22 <- data.frame(RSI(Cl(Data), n=22))
```

what you're doing is wrapping the results in a data frame and then *embedding it an another data frame* (`Data`), which is something you can legally do in R but which is unusual and confuses a lot of the standard data-processing functions.

Comment: It returns me the following error: Error in complete.cases(Data) : not all arguments have the same length. However, I checked my df has even length across all columns...

Comment: Did you follow my advice about building `Data` in a different way?  (see the first row of my code)

Comment: wow, it works. Can you please explain a wee bit why this works? I just need to understand..

Answer (score 0):

You could try `complete.cases`

```
DatanoNA <- Data[complete.cases(Data),]
```

Comment: this is good but won't work on the OP's example because they built their data frame in a funny way (see my answer).